# MemoryError: Unable to allocate 64.0 KiB for an array with shape (1, 128, 128) and data type float32

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to perform segmentation using a CNN approach and used the keras ImageDataGenerator to generate more data and fed them into my network.
whenever I run the code I get this error

File "C:\Users\abirf\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\deep_learning\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 434, in stack
return _nx.concatenate(expanded_arrays, axis=axis, out=out)

File "<**array_function** internals>", line 6, in concatenate

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 64.0 KiB for an array with shape (1, 128, 128) and data type float32

what's the problem exactly ?

this is a snippet of my code

```
X_path= os.path.join('.........../train_data/', 'images') # input image
Y_path = os.path.join('........./train_data/', 'masks') # ground-truth label

 
# we create two instances with the same arguments
data_gen_args = dict(featurewise_center=True,
                     featurewise_std_normalization=True,
                     rotation_range=45.,
                     width_shift_range=0.1,
                     height_shift_range=0.1,
                     zoom_range=[0.2])


seed = 1 
image_datagen =ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
mask_datagen =ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

image_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(X_path, class_mode=None,batch_size=16, seed=seed,target_size=(img_col,img_row),color_mode='grayscale')
mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(Y_path, class_mode=None,batch_size=16, seed=seed,target_size=(img_col, img_row),color_mode='grayscale')

train_generator =  zip(image_generator, mask_generator)

num_train = len(image_generator)
#########################################################

   this contains the architecture used to perform the training

#########################################################
history = model.fit(list(train_generator), steps_per_epoch=num_train, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.1 , batch_size=16, epochs=50,callbacks=[earlystopper, checkpointer])
```

Comment: You’re using too much memory. Try freeing some arrays you no longer need, or buy more RAM.

Comment: Is there anything that I can change  in the program ? @CrisLuengo

Comment: Of course! But I can’t give you advice because I have no idea what your program looks like. See [mre], then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: I just addaed the part of the code used for the augmentaion ! Note : all my images and labels are already resized to a size (128,128) @CrisLuengo